# Visual Basic "Index was outside the bounds of the array" (Mean Calculator Program)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a Mean Calculator (program that adds several items together (seperated by ",") and divides them by the number of items there, also known as Average). I'm going to school to learn Visual Basic and other languages like C# and Web Development, so I think eventually I'll learn this there, but I don't want to wait. I say that if I can learn something before school, then school will be refinery and mastery.

Here's the code, as it stands. (Visual Studio 13).

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim dblDivide As Double
    Dim Input As New String = txtInput.Text
    Dim Delimeter As Char = ","
    Dim Substrings() = Input.Split(Delimeter)
    Dim dblTotal As Double
    Dim dblMean As Double

    Double.TryParse(txtDivideBy.Text, dblDivide)

    For Each substring In Substrings
        dblTotal = substring(0) + substring(1)
        dblMean = dblTotal / dblDivide
    Next
    lblMean.Text = dblMean.ToString("N2")
End Sub
```

Any time I try to run the code, using the numbers 2 2 and 2 (which should return 2, ((2+2)/2) = 2), line 13 returns the IndexOutOfRangeException. Eventually I want to change the program so instead of using a "Divide By" input (txtDivideBy.Text and dblDivide), I want it to divide it by the number of substrings. I tried replacing "dblDivide" in line 14 with "Substrings()" and it gave me another error.

Comment: What happens when you use the step-through debugger?

Comment: For Each substring In Substrings
        dblTotal = substring(0) + substring(1)
        dblMean = dblTotal / dblDivide
    Next
The dblTotal always is substring(0) + substring(1), no For Each loop here needed.

Comment: Anytime I use the Step-Through Debugger it says it's switched to step over and then it does nothing but normal debugging, Dai (I wonder if I need to add something to the installer for this to work. We have Visual Studio 13 at my school and it says the same thing there too). I was just adding something so I could try and figure it out. That was a place holder, Tony Dong

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting an error on the second line because of your use of `New`. This is not necessary for declaring the string.

```
Dim Input As New String = txtInput.Text
```

Your index out of bounds is because you're trying to access a sub element of `substring` as though it were an array. But it's not, it's a string. `For Each` iterates over each element in `Substrings` and sets `substring` to `Substrings(i)` where `i` is the current index. So, just keep adding `substring` to `dblTotal` to get your total.

```
For Each substring In Substrings
    dblTotal = dblTotal + subString
Next
```

You don't need to divide the total for every iteration of the loop, so move it outside of the loop.

```
dblMean = dblTotal / dblDivide
```

To get the number of items in the `Substrings` array, you can use the `Length` property of an array.

```
dblMean = dblTotal / Substrings.Length
```

Complete modified code.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim Delimeter As Char = ","
    Dim Substrings() = Input.Split(Delimeter)
    Dim dblTotal As Double
    Dim dblMean As Double

    For Each substring In Substrings
        dblTotal = dblTotal + substring
    Next
    dblMean = dblTotal / Substrings.Length
    lblMean.Text = dblMean.ToString("N2")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. I thought it only worked when I entered 1 or 2 numbers and I was going to respond, but I realized I failed to calculate (10 + 10 + 10) / 3 correctly, thinking it's 15 and not 10. I did it with 10, 11, and 12 and I got 11, which the Microsoft calculator backs up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is from accessing the second character of the one character string: `substring(1)`

Learning about [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384667.aspx) might be a bit more useful in the long run:

```
Dim query = From s In Split(txtInput.Text, ",") Select Val(s)
lblMean.Text = query.Average.ToString("N2")
```

or a bit shorter

```
lblMean.Text = Format(Split(txtInput.Text, ",").Average(AddressOf Val), "N2")
```

The [`Val`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0) function returns 0 if no numbers are found in the string.